# mirth Failed to write to database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to connect to my our database and write on it

but i have error

```
ERROR (com.mirth.connect.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseDispatcher:113): An error occurred in channel "send": Failed to write to database
 java.sql.SQLException: String or binary data would be truncated. 
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:613)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:572)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.execute(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:784)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseDispatcherQuery.send(DatabaseDispatcherQuery.java:120)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseDispatcher.send(DatabaseDispatcher.java:103)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.DestinationConnector.handleSend(DestinationConnector.java:822)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.DestinationConnector.process(DestinationConnector.java:476)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.DestinationChain.doCall(DestinationChain.java:121)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.DestinationChain.call(DestinationChain.java:63)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.Channel.process(Channel.java:1715)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.Channel.dispatchRawMessage(Channel.java:1198)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.SourceConnector.dispatchRawMessage(SourceConnector.java:192)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.SourceConnector.dispatchRawMessage(SourceConnector.java:170)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.file.FileReceiver.processFile(FileReceiver.java:354)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.file.FileReceiver.processFiles(FileReceiver.java:247)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.file.FileReceiver.poll(FileReceiver.java:203)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.PollConnectorJob.execute(PollConnectorJob.java:49)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
```

please help me !

this is my code in sql:

```
INSERT INTO Persons ([SurName])
VALUES (${fname})
```

Answer (score 0):

At least one of the strings(or binary field) you are trying to insert is too long for the size of the datatype in your database.

1. Check the length of the values you are trying to insert with the maximum size of the correlating data types in your database.
2. Make sure that you are inserting the values into the correct columns by specifying the columns in the `insert` in the same order you are selecting them or listing them as values.

Comment: this is my code in sql

   INSERT INTO Persons ([SurName])

VALUES

(${fname})

Comment: @PureéAd What is the datatype and size of `Persons.Surname` and how long is the `fname` you are trying to insert?

Answer (score 0):

1. your fname may be of more size than the one you initialized in your Persons table of DB. (99% the cause for this error)
2. Check the datatype of your column Surname and the fname datatype you are inserting. (20% the cause of this error).
3. Make sure your fname string does not contain special characters (99% this will not be reason for the error), but I have experienced Mirth giving same error when special characters are used.
4. Above all make sure your channel "send" is configured properly to write it to DB.